# Escaping backslashes when using write.table

Tags: r

I have some strings in one of the columns of my data frame that look like:
    *bem\\2015\black.rec*

When I export the data frame into a text file using the next line:

```
write.table(data, file = "sample.txt", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, sep = '\t')
```

Then in the text file the text looks like:
    *bem\2015BELblack.rec*

Do you know an easy way to ignore all backslashes when writing the table into a text file so the backslashes are kept.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to remove the backlashes *before* the `write.table` call?

Comment: I need them in the final/export table because they are part of the data. Removing them would be altering these data, why are not mine and, in addition, the backslashes have a meaning for the data provider.

Comment: You can just replace all \ with \\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They way I have resolved this is converting backslashes into forwardslashes:

```
dataset <- read_delim(dataset.path, delim = '\t', col_names = TRUE, escape_backslash = FALSE)
dataset$columnN <- str_replace_all(dataset$Levfile, "\\\\", "//")
dataset$columnN <- str_replace_all(dataset$Levfile, "//", "/")
write.table(dataset, file = "sample.txt", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, sep = '\t')
```

This exports the text imported as *bem\\2015\black.rec* with the required slashes: *bem//2015/black.rec*